# When I try to render an animation in cycles my character shows up as completely black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

Everything else in the animation shows up as completely fine except for my character. I'm very inexperienced (this is my first animation) so the fix might be something painfully obvious.
[image]

The texture for the arms and legs is also glitched in the viewport model but even while they were glitched they rendered correctly in earlier wip renders.
[image]

I am using blender 2.9

Comment: Hello and welcome. Are you rendering with workbench like in the second image ? or are you using a different render engine for your final render?

Comment: The error occurs when i render in cycles sorry for the confusion. @Emir

Comment: @Emir sorry for the confusion I had only switched to workbench for a second while i was trying to figure out the problem, I adjusted the lighting in cycles. I think that the issue has something to to with the material itself. I'm sorry I'm not articulating my issue very well. If you would like I can send you the .blend file.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do your final render in cycles, make sure to adjuste the lights in the viewport using Cycles Engine, so could have the same result in the final render. Workbech in viewport it's going to look different from cycles

[image]